# Interpreting CSN.1 notation from 3GPP standards 44.060

Tags: networking, 3g, specifications

If someone could explain in clear English what the following CSN.1 means I would be very grateful.  It is taken from [3GPP 44.060 version 8.10.0](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/44_series/44.060/44060-8a0.zip) in section 11.2.6e for the EGPRS2 PACKET DOWNLINK ACK/NACK TYPE 2 information element.

> ```
>   { 0 | 1     < EPD A/N Extension Type 2 length : bit (8) >
>             < bit (val(EPD A/N Extension length) + 1)
>             & { < EPD A/N Extension Info Type 2 > ! { bit** = <no string> }} > }
> ```

Where the element EPD A/N Extension Type 2 Info is described as a variable length set of elements.

The meaning as I understand it is the element is conditional.  If a 1 is present in the stream then follows 8 bits of the EPD A/N Extension Type 2 length, followed by a bit string of this length + 1, but what is the purpose of the *& { < EPD A/N Extension Info Type 2 >*?

My assumption is that it is simply to explicitly state that this bit string is the EPD A/N Extension Info Type 2 information element.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would point you towards http://csn1.info/csn1_other_rules.html to have a look at intersections and error indications.

The intersection, &, is to make sure the < EPD A/N Extension Info Type 2 > element fits onto the bitstring bit(val(EPD A/N Extension Length)+1), and limits the length of the < EPD A/N Extension Info Type 2 > element to the length of the bitstring. If it did not limit the length, the < spare padding > in < EPD A/N Extension Info Type 2 > would consume all remaining bits.

The error indication, !, states that if the < EPD A/N Extension Info Type 2 > element does not fit onto the bitstring an error should be flagged and the bitstring discarded.